# Error on App Store submission: A symbolic link resolves to a location outside of the binary

Tags: iphone, ios, validation, cocoapods

The project compiles and links fine, but when I go to submit/validate I get this error:

```
The Binary is invalid. A symbolic link resolves to a location outside of the binary relative location:
    xxxx.app/Appirater.bundle resolves to Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedDate/xxxxx/intermediatebuildfilespath/uninstalledproducts/Appirater.bundle
```

I'm using CocoaPods for the first time and have Appirater and another pod installed.

Comment: I don't know too much about CocoaPods and Appirater but from what I can gather, it looks like you have a resource that isn't in the the project folder and not being included in the project therefore it is linking to a file outside of what will be the compiled project.

Comment: @evan.stoddard thanks for responding, im just ripping out appirater via cocoapods and putting it in old school. one thing ill say is i have another dependency used in cocoapods and its not choking on that so maybe its something to do with appirater cocoapod situation.

Comment: Well all I can really gather is you are referencing to something it is outside your compiled project and that is all I can really gather.  Any images or libraries and do it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in the Podfile/Repository of Appirater. I'm sure it will be fixed shortly.

If you don't need the very latest version, you can change your Podfile to say the following:

```
pod 'Appirater', '1.0.5'
```

Don't forget to clean your build folder in Xcode.

Comment: this sounds like a good answer but I can't check it now :(, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Clean your buil folder in xcode and delete Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedDate/xxxxx/intermediatebuildfilespath/uninstalledproducts/Appirater.bundle

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me solution was to update cocoapods to 0.28 (sudo gem install cocoapods). This solution was mention on: https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/issues/133. After that i can commit my application to app store.